# Error Code 1136: INTERT INTO COMMAND

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a assessment.

```
USE Exams;

INSERT INTO students
VALUES
(student_id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email),
('11', 'Emily', 'Ralph', 'Jane', 'CJKAKDWE@gmail.co.uk', '7171', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
('12', 'Elana', '', 'Smith', 'ELANASmith@gmail.co.uk', 'GJKAKIWAH', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
('13', 'Aedan', '', 'Lawrenece', 'AIDANL@gmail.co.uk', 'AIDJENKGA', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
('14', 'Maxine', '', 'Caulfield', 'MAXISPRO@gmail.co.uk', 'ENCRYPTED', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
('15', 'Chloe', 'ELizabeth', 'Price', 'Chloeprice@OutLook.com', 'WIlliam190', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
('16', 'Herbie', 'James', 'Hall', 'HERBIEJ@gmail.co.uk', 'BEACHDGJK', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
('17', 'Nathan', 'Josh', 'Presscott', 'NATHANJPress@gmail.co.uk', '71789072', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
('18', 'Natalie', 'Dust', 'Dormer', 'NATALIEDD@OutLook.com', 'IWTBq+', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');


SELECT count(*) FROM students;
```

I thought that it was correct but I just jeep getting

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I know it must be due to spelling authentication or i've just missed out a comma or something to do with the syntax.
I don't see what the problem Is :/

[image]

Can anyone help please!

Thank you.

Comment: you are missing 2 column names in insert statement. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong. The syntax is

```
INSERT INTO sometable (list,of,fields) VALUES (values,to,insert)
```

You have

```
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (list,of,fields), (values,to,insert)
```

Since you didn't specify a field list properly, the db is properly complaining that you didn't provide enough values to fill in all of the non-default-value fields in the table. Plus, you can't insert a field into itself...

Plus, you have **5** fields list in your badly-posistioned field list, but are providing **7** values:

```
(student_id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email),
    1          2            3          4        5
('11', 'Emily', 'Ralph', 'Jane', 'CJKAKDWE@gmail.co.uk', '7171', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
   1      2       3        4           5                    6        7
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Column names are missing here:
`(student_id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email)`

Insert statement has 2 more columns:

```
('11', 'Emily', 'Ralph', 'Jane', 'CJKAKDWE@gmail.co.uk', '7171', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
```

---

```
INSERT INTO students
    VALUES
    (student_id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email),
    ('11', 'Emily', 'Ralph', 'Jane', 'CJKAKDWE@gmail.co.uk', '7171', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    ('12', 'Elana', '', 'Smith', 'ELANASmith@gmail.co.uk', 'GJKAKIWAH', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    ('13', 'Aedan', '', 'Lawrenece', 'AIDANL@gmail.co.uk', 'AIDJENKGA', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    ('14', 'Maxine', '', 'Caulfield', 'MAXISPRO@gmail.co.uk', 'ENCRYPTED', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    ('15', 'Chloe', 'ELizabeth', 'Price', 'Chloeprice@OutLook.com', 'WIlliam190', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    ('16', 'Herbie', 'James', 'Hall', 'HERBIEJ@gmail.co.uk', 'BEACHDGJK', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    ('17', 'Nathan', 'Josh', 'Presscott', 'NATHANJPress@gmail.co.uk', '71789072', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    ('18', 'Natalie', 'Dust', 'Dormer', 'NATALIEDD@OutLook.com', 'IWTBq+', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```